# Partial fractions in Mathematica vs. Wolfram Alpha

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have the irreducible fraction: $$\frac{t^2}{t^4+1}$$ When I use the function "apart" in mathematica the output is $\frac{t^2}{t^4+1}$, which means that it was not able to find a way to factor the denominator, instead when I use "apart" in wolfram alpha, I get $$-\frac{t}{2\sqrt2(-t^2+\sqrt2t-1)}-\frac{t}{2\sqrt2(t^2+\sqrt2t+1)}$$
which is correct. Does anyone know how or why the "apart" function gives different results in mathematica and wolfra alpha (i am strictly talking about irreducible fractions)

Comment: Hi user372003 It is not my intention to criticize but please do not accept the answer I provided for a period of 24 hours. This gives others the chance and impetus to answer. I have never taken back an accepted answer so I do not even know if it is possible but if you can I will not be offended.

Comment: @bobbym I'll keep in mind for next time! However, the answer you gave me, was the on I was looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe Alpha is calling additional commands behind the scene.

```
Factor[t^2/(t^4 + 1), Extension -> Sqrt[2]]
```

will break it apart but not exactly as you have.

To do better

```
Factor[t^2/(t^4 + 1), Extension -> Sqrt[2]]//Apart
```

as Bob Hanlon points out below.

Comment: Thank you! That might have been the problem

Comment: Let us wait for more users to answer and then we will see.

Comment: `Factor[t^2/(t^4 + 1), Extension -> Sqrt[2]] // Apart`